# Security issues with jLinq

Tags: security

I stumbled upon jLinq through the open source ads in stackoverflow.
The possibilities are astonishing but I am wondering.
What kind of datasets I shouldn't be using it on?
As those datasets run on the client they could be modified using the URL: javascript: ...
What should be done to prevent rewriting of data?
How do I authenticate that I am the only one that is changing or selecting it?

Comment: Please pose questions one-at-a-time. Or make it community wiki if you really want to elicit random opinions.

Comment: This question is not about my opinion but about the possible security issues with using a client side dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jLinq is strictly for working with client side JSON data ([although you can do some neat stuff with server side databases like MongoDB](http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/jlinq-in-mongodb-oh-snap/)). Since anything can be modified by the client at any time you should always validate the information fed back to the server.

Comment: How do I validate those things? You mean I should check for valid input? But what if the input is valid and still somehow incorrect?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you're trying to do but if you're going to send something back up to the server then the server needs to validate that information as well. If you're trying to validate something for the page itself then you can give it your best effort and throw an exception when you don't like the response.

Feel free to contact me and we can discuss it further (contact form on my website in my profile)